# Is there a way to retrieve a kubernetes resource at a specific resourceVersion?

Tags: kubernetes

I know that I can Watch for changes from a resourceVersion, what I want is a way to GET the resource at a specific resourceVersion.

Comment: Hi, Can you please provide some more context/details to understand the question.

Comment: Can you provide some sample config, and what you are trying to GET specifically?

Answer (score 1):

If you are the admin of k8s cluster, then you can retrieve that through etcd directly.